# Primefaces: How to get datatable column filter component

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

Is there a solution to set a "DefaultValue" for the "filterBy" Component ??
I mean more precisely ... How can I set the value of the component shown in the picture ?

http://www.pictureupload.de/originals/pictures/111012170732_primefaces.png

Or how can I set a defaultValue for the option "filtering" in the p:column?!

```
            <p:column id="artikelVerkaufDatum" headerText="Datum" filterBy="#{sales.dateForFilter}"
                filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                <h:outputText id="date" value="#{sales.datum}">
                    <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:MM:ss" />
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
```

Ok ... another question ... My FireBug says that the component exists with ... but i cannot access it with for example: something like FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent ... I always get a NullpointerException :(

```
<th id="artikelVerkauf:datatable:artikelVerkaufDatum" class="ui-state-default ui-filter-column" role="columnheader">
<div class="ui-dt-c">
<span>Datum</span>
<input id="artikelVerkauf:datatable:artikelVerkaufDatum_filter" class="ui-column-filter ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" autocomplete="off" value="" name="artikelVerkauf:datatable:artikelVerkaufDatum_filter" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-multiline="false">
</div>
</th>
```

If anybody has any idea ... please let me know ! every help is welcomed :)
Regards Sway

Comment: in order to get better/more accurate answers it would be good to separate your questions. [If you ask several questions in one question you risk having answers that are both correct and wrong at the same time.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts)

Comment: For your first question look [here](http://www.bradchen.com/2012/05/persist-primefaces-datatable-state-across-refresh)

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution I used once (PF 3.5):

- First set *widgetVar="tableWidget"* for the datatable.
- Assign a *filterStyleClass="my-column-filter"* for the *p:column* that is filtered
- Then insert the following JavaScript which will be executed after the DOM is ready:

  $( document ).ready(function() {
       $('.my-column-filter').val('default'); 
       tableWidget.filter();
  });

Good luck!